# Is it possible to create popup windows for login/folder selection in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

i have written the following mini script that pulls my current source code from the repository. If the repository already exists on the machine, then the new state should be pulled.
Now to my question:

Currently the location where the repositories are hard coded just like the credentials for bitbucket. But I would like to have something like popup window where you can specify the desired location. For the credentials of bitbucket a login window would be desirable.
Would these popup windows be possible and if so how could I implement them? Thanks in advance

```
# Lade die Repositories herunter
$updateRepositories = 
{
    if( -not (Test-Path -Path D:\Test\database1 -PathType Any ))
    {
        git clone https://.../.../database1.git
    }
    else
    {
        Set-Location D:\Test\database1
        git pull https://.../.../database1.git
    }

    if( -not (Test-Path -Path D:\Test\service -PathType Any ))
    {
        git clone https://.../.../service.git
    }
    else
    {
        Set-Location D:\Test\service
        git pull https://.../.../service.git
    }

    if( -not (Test-Path -Path D:\Test\website -PathType Any ))
    {
        git clone https://.../.../website.git
    }
    else
    {
        Set-Location D:\Test\website
        git pull https://.../.../website.git
    }

    if( -not (Test-Path -Path D:\Test\api -PathType Any ))
    {
        git clone https://.../.../api.git
    }
    else
    {
        Set-Location D:\Test\api
        git pull https:.../.../api.git
    }
    if( -not (Test-Path -Path D:\Test\database2 -PathType Any ))
    {
        git clone https://.../.../database2.git
    }
    else
    {
        Set-Location D:\Test\database2
        git pull https://.../.../database2.git
    }
    Set-Location D:\Test
}
```

Comment: Is the prompt/pop-up generated by `Get-Credential` fitting for your use case? That'd by far be the easiest proxy for inputting the credentials :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not sure. I am currently using git pull https://bitbucketUsername@bitbucket.org/folder
I don't know how to pull the individual repositories after logging in to bitBucket. The username would probably have to be stored in a variable after that and then built into the git pull command or?

Comment: Well, who's going to say whether it's good enough, if not you? :) Open PowerShell, type the command `Get-Credential` - once you hit enter, PowerShell will prompt you for credentials. Take a look at the prompt, try inputting some dummu credentials. Is that the user experience you're hoping for?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have solved it now:

to be able to select a folder where I have the repositories I used the following source code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$browser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
$browser.Description = 'Wähle einen Ordner in dem die Repositories abgelegt werden sollen.'
$null = $browser.ShowDialog((New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{TopMost = $true }))
$path=$browser.SelectedPath
```